# blocking CORs from origin

Tags: cors

Trying to understand CORs

If my site, http://example.com is trying to make a request to api.yelp.com, I get that Yelp would need to authorize the cross-origin call with Access-Control-Allow-Origin. However, my colleague is saying that http://example.com also needs a special config to allow the call api.yelp.com. If I read about CORs, I see nothing about the origin site, in this case http://example.com blocking a CORs call. The browser does by default, but it can be allowed to make the CORs call without special permission from the origin. Is this correct, or am i missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Ajax requests, [all CORS configuration](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) needs to be done on the target server only.

As you've said, `api.yelp.com` needs to respond with an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header of either `*` or `http://example.com`. If the request has any non-simple components (HTTP verb other than `GET` or `POST`, and/or any non-simple headers) then `api.yelp.com` must also respond with the appropriate `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` and/or `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response headers. However, these headers are also part of the configuration on `api.yelp.com`, not for `example.com`.

Perhaps your colleague is thinking of the [Content Security Policy](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/) (CSP), wihch allows a page to *restrict* target origins for Ajax requests, images, media, scripts, and styles. All origins are allowed by default, but when you add a CSP, you can restrict permitted origins to a specific whitelist. If your site uses a CSP whitelist for the `connect-src` directive, you may need to add `api.yelp.com` to its CSP whitelist.

In short, `example.com` does not need to *permit* an Ajax call to `api.yelp.com`, but it may choose to *deny* such a call, via a CSP directive. (And therefore, if such a denial is already in place, you may need to relax it.)